# Set frootvpn as global VPN

Tags: 14.04, internet, vpn, openvpn

I can't set frootvpn as default VPN layer in my Ubuntu 14.04.
Following the [official guide](https://www.frootvpn.com/guides/linuxdebian-19.html) I succeded in activating it for the time being, but after restarting I have to do the last step again.
I tried importing default config file (using network manager settings-->new-->VPN-->import settings), but it won't let me save the new profile, guess some entries are missing.
[as you can see, "save" button is not clickable]
Any guess?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for translate. You problem is that CA Certificate box is empty. 
Read this: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki
Is the best source for your problem.

Comment: Certificato CA (Nessuno) = CA certificate (None)  , exactly as you guessed, though I don't really know what that certificate is and, above all, where I can get it

Comment: Impostazioni=Settings  Autenticazione=Autentication  Generale=general  Tipo=type  Nome utente=Username  salvata=saved  Mostra le password=Show passwords  Avanzate=Advanced(advanced settings)  Annulla=Cancel  Salva=Save

Comment: Here it is, if you need anything else just ask me. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Plus, the conf file works just fine when I run it through my terminal. Now that I had to import it, it points out that something is missing.